# It's possible use cordova plugin not listed in ngCordova?

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have an app developed with Ionic framwork + Angular and I need use a cordova plugin ([cordova-plugin-iosrtc](https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc)) and my question is, it possible use this plugin with even not listed on ngCordova?

I'm new on these technologies and I'm a little lost....

thanks.

Comment: Yes you can use plugin and its methods as stated in documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @hva.narola. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely. ngCordova is just an optional thin wrapper around some plugins' JS to (usually) make using the plugin JS easier or more Angular friendly. You don't need to use ngCordova at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.